# Spring Integration - programmatically create / teardown channels

Tags: spring, spring-integration

**Is it possible to programmatically create / teardown Spring Integration channels, as opposed to declaring them statically in Spring config?**

My situation is this:

I have a webapp that requires push notifications, so I'm using long polling.  Those long polling calls need to block on the server until they get an event.

What I'm envisioning (open to alternatives, of course), is a Spring Integration queue channel for *each session*, each listening to a single pubsub channel.  So, when a server event happens it will be published to the pubsub, which will then pipe down to the individual session queues where they'll be popped off and sent to the client that's polling.

In order to do this, when a session is created I'd have to register new queue channel listing on the pubsub channel.  When the session is destroyed, that new queue will also be destroyed.

Is something like this possible?

I don't want to have the the session listening directly to the pubsub because there's a risk of losing messages, so I want to have a queue in between to buffer them.

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can simply instantiate a `QueueChannel` and make it the `outputChannel` of a `BridgeHandler`. Then create an `EventDrivenConsumer`, passing the pubSub and bridge handler in the constructor.

Call `start()` on the consumer to make it subscribe to the pubSub, and `stop()` to unsubscribe when the session is closed.

If you don't want to hand-wire these components, simply declare the queue channel, and bridge in a small application context; make it a child of your main context and it will automatically subscribe to the pubSub in the parent context. Call `context.destroy()` to disconnect.

Comment: Brilliant.  For anyone else in need I've created a gist for a code sample: https://gist.github.com/roytruelove/7589536

Comment: One other cavet to this - channels always have to have at least one subscriber if someone tries to post a message to it.  Since we're creating subscribes dynamically, it could happen that a given channel does not yet have subscribers.  To get around this, you need to subscribe to the pubsub channel with (at least) a NullChannel.

Comment: A point-to-point `SubscribableChannel` (e.g. `DirectChannel`) cannot have zero subscribers but, like with JMS topics, a PubSub channel can have zero subscribers and the message is just dropped. This can be modified with the `minSubscribers` property, but the default is zero. The behavior can be examined with DEBUG logging.

Comment: Correction - sorry - that's the behavior of the channel itself; however some senders will detect zero recipients and throw an exception. This includes the `MessagingTemplate`, which is used by the framework internally to send messages. So your solution will solve that too.

Comment: I believe this is changing in 3.0 but we're still on the release version for now.

Comment: Sorry (again); yes in 3.0, the behavior has been changed such that no exception is thrown by the template when there are zero subscribers.