# Spring Integration - make pubsub block

Tags: spring-integration

I'd like to make a thread block until it gets a pubsub messages.  There doesn't seem to be a way to do this because PublishSubscribeChannel doesn't implement PollingChannel.  The only option is to subscribe with a MessageHandler, but that handler won't be able to block on the same thread.  Is there an alternative?

I've also looked at the MessagingTemplate class but it doesn't seem to support this either.

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 2):

See the answer to your other question...

[Spring Integration - programmatically create / teardown channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126706/spring-integration-programmatically-create-teardown-channels/20127516#20127516)

Just set the timeout to -1 (or some very large number) on the `receive()`.

When the publisher sends to the pubsub; it will invoke the (subscribed) bridge, which will send to the message to the QueueChannel and hand off to the blocked thread.

Comment: Thanks Gary - this case is a little bit different - In this case I'd have (say) 100 threads listening to the same pubsub waiting for messages.  I could, again, create a QueueChannel in each thread but it feels like overkill since it's ok if I lose messages.  I'd expect that pubsub should be able to block without having to bridge it with a QueueChannel

Comment: PS - just noticed that you're the lead committer on Spring Integration so maybe I'll question your answers a little bit less ;)

Comment: No problem :) SI has two channel types `PollableChannel` (queue, priority, rendezvous) and `SubscribableChannel` (direct, executor, pubsub). It sounds like you want a channel where any thread that is sitting in `receive()` would get the message. We don't have anything like that. You could write a very lightweight `MessageHandler` that has an internal `BlockingQueue` and a receive method. When a caller invokes `receive()`, it could do `pubsub.subscribe(this)` then wait on a poll of the internal queue. The `handleMessage()` would add to the queue. You would unsubscribe when no longer interested.